# Is there a script/macro which includes figures, having 3 arguments: 1) input file, 2) caption and 3) scale?

Tags: macros, scripts

I'm looking for a macro like,

```
\newcommand{\figu}[3]{
\begin{figure}[H]
\scalebox{#3}
{\begin{center}
{\includegraphics[width=13 cm, height=8 cm]{#1}}
\end{center}}

\vspace{-0.2cm}
\caption{\hspace{0.25cm}#2\label{f:#1}}
\end{figure}
}
```

This does not work, but works fine if I erase the `\scalebox`. Thanks.

Comment: remove the scalebox (you can not have vertical material in scalebox, and (pehaps) add a scale= option to includegraphics (depending what you want this to do)  Note it is usually wrong to specify both height= and width= as that distorts the image, just use one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `\scalebox` works in `center`, but not the other way round; and a `center` environment within a `figure` environment is usually frowned upon since it introduces unwanted vertical space, see [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651/82917). I propose here a slightly different implementation

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,float}

\newcommand{\figu}[3][]{
\begin{figure}[H] % <--- do you REALLY need/want this?
\centering
\includegraphics[#1]{#2}
\vspace{-0.2cm}% <--- do you REALLY need/want this?
\caption{\hspace{0.25cm}% <--- do you REALLY need/want this?
#3\label{f:#2}}
\end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

\figu[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}{Caption of one figure}

\figu[scale=.4]{example-image-b}{Caption of another figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I find it very strange that you force a 13/8 ratio for *all* pictures; also the vertical and horizontal spaces you are inserting manually look *very* suspicious to me.

Comment: thanks! it seems however that the first argument must be typed in full "scale=...", I guess typing "scale=..." cannot be avoided that easily

Comment: @florin It can, but there might be situations where you want to pass different options. You can replace this code by `\includegraphics[scale=#1]{#2}` but then you will be allowed to pass only the `scale` option to `\includegraphics`. In my experience this is counter-productive.